# How to update a nested document in a mongodb with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I hope someone can help me to understand how I can update a document in a mongodb.
My problem is that i have a document which contains an array. And in this array there are objects with a specific ID(like you would find in sql database). Now I want to update the data inside those objects if they have the searched id.

A document looks like this

```
{
    "_id": "63dafa72f21d48312d8ca405",
    "tasks": [{
        "_ref": "63d8d8d01beb0b606314e322",
        "data": {
            "values": [{
                "key": "Deadline",
                "value": "2014-10-13"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "_ref": "84dd046c6695e32322d842f5",
        "data": {
            "values": []
        }
    }]
}
```

I did write the method updateProject

```
public bool updateProject(Project pro, Project dbPro)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("projects");
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", dbPro.Id);
        var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("tasks", pro.Tasks);
        var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
        if (result.IsModifiedCountAvailable)
        {
            if (result.ModifiedCount == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

And thats how a project does look like in c#.

```
class Project{
    public string id;
    public List<Task> Tasks;
}

class Task{
   public string id;
   public List<Value> Values;
}

class Value{
   public String key;
   public String value;
}
```

but i cant figure out how i can go deeper to find the searched id.

Comment: i believe when you searched id you are referring to the _ref id. right ?

Comment: on a second look. i guess you question is not very clear. You want to match documents inside tasks based on _ref and make an update to them. am i correct ?

Comment: Yes thats it satish. I have a collection called task and I use the _ref as kind of foreign key to connect it with the id of the object of task. Im sorry that it wasn´t clear.

Comment: I will try to explain it better what im trying to do. In a step befor i did generate from a excel sheet a project. Thats my first parameter. Then my program looks which project in my database has the most matches with my generated project. The user has then the possbility to check the one thats fits best. Thats my 2nd parameter. Now I need to find the project again in the database and update all tasks in the database out of my generated project. The database project can have an unlimited amount of tasks, but I need to update only the tasks with the same _ref.